# How to get value from service constructor in angular2 service

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am trying to work out an Auth Service. 
I am using this :

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  authState: any = null;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private db: AngularFireDatabase,
              private router:Router) {

            this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((auth) => {
              this.authState = auth;

            });
          }

  // Returns true if user is logged in
  get authenticated(): boolean {
    return this.authState !== null;
  }
```

The authenticated() function keep giving me false, even  if a user is logged in.

When I console.log the authState (this.authState) in the constructor, I do get a value, but outside the constructor , this.authState is null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you using the service? I mean have you declared it as provider at app level or component level. Can you share the component code that accesses the authenticated function?

Comment: Subscribe method is async. If you call authenticated method before subscribe is fired, you'll get false.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner, what would be the way out to solve this?

Comment: Make your method returns an Observable like Yordan suggests

Answer (score 0):

The better way would be to have separate function

```
authenticated(): Observable<User> {
    return this.afAuth.authState;
  }
```

then in your component you can subscribe to this method, like you did in your service constructor

Edited!

Comment: [ts] Type 'Observable<User>' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

Comment: I just forgot to change the return type ;] try now

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to Complicate the matter

In your Component where you require the value do this

```
authState : boolean;

constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {

            this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((auth) => {
              this.authState = ( auth !== null ) ? true : false;

            });
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **APP_INITIALIZER** to wait for the async operation to complete.Please check the below code:

AuthService.ts

```
  @Injectable()
  export class AuthService {
      authState: any = null;
     constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
          private db: AngularFireDatabase,
          private router:Router) {

      }
  loadValue(){
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((auth) => {
              this.authState = auth;
              resolve(true);
           });
      }); 
  }
  // Returns true if user is logged in
 get authenticated(): boolean {
   return this.authState !== null;
 }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';

 @NgModule({
  //...
  providers: [AuthService, 
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: (authService: AuthService) => () => authService.loadValue(),
        deps: [AuthService],
        multi: true
    }]
  ///....
 })
```

Hope it helps!!